# Mysql select and get data from a row

Tags: php, mysql

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "secure_login");

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT members FROM hannes")) {
        echo $result->row['firstlogin'];

        $result->close();
    }
```

I'm quite new to Mysql and I have a problem where I want to get the value of the row "firstlogin" from the user "hannes"

My table looks like this (table name is "members")

```
Username  firstlogin
hannes        0
rachel        2
adam          1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mysqli->query("SELECT firstlogin FROM members WHER Username='hannes'"))` is the correct query. In `select` you have to put the name of the fields / column and in the `WHERE` the name of the table

Comment: You should take a SQL tutorial first since this is the very basic stuff of SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT `firstlogin` FROM `members` where `Username`='hannes'")
```

Full code: You  need to use fetch_row to get the rows from table as like below, if you have multiple rows in your table then you need to use `while` loop. In your case you have only one record so there is no need of `while` loop

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `firstlogin` FROM `members` where `Username`='hannes'")) {        
 $row = $result->fetch_array();
 echo $row['firstlogin'];
 $result->close();
}
```

Comment: And then just echo $result? to get the value of firstlogin *EDIT* how do i convert the output of $result to a string?

Comment: I am getting an "Undefined index: firstlogin"